# Labelling polygon with multiple values from Attribute table

Tags: labeling, attribute-table, arcgis-pro, features

What is a good way to put a list of names in one polygon feature?

For example, I'm creating a County Facilities layer. There are cases when you have multiple departments in the same building.

I don't want separate polygons for these departments, but be able to label them from the same polygon.

Comment: Using a lookup table perhaps - https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012230

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create multiple fields for each facility and then create customized labels out of them. Check the image below

[image]

Comment: While this solution technically works on a smaller scale, if you need to label based on buildings with more than 3 departments, you'll need a different solution.  Granted, you will probably want to avoid labelling after a certain number of departments or your map will get too cluttered.  Your best bet though is to create a table separate from the buildings feature class, and label using an expression.

Comment: Out of curiosity: Why don't the labels of FID 0 and FID 1 say "Police Dept, Sheriff Dept, " and "District Court, Civil Court, " in the answer above?

Comment: I wonder if ArcGIS Pro counts that last comma as "extra spaces" when checked?

Comment: @maxwhere I am sorry! I did not understand what you trying to say

Comment: @ZacharyOrdo-GISP I think extra spaces are only leftover spaces after the string per field. For example, text field length = 15 text, field value = "Tax Office" and extra spaces = 5

Comment: @Amadeus Obyiously the field "Facility3" of FID 0 is empty (or contains a space idk) so according to your expression there should be a tailing comma in the label but there is none. I wonder why.

Comment: Sorry, I understood what you meant now. I guess developers thought about this kind of situation and put a mechanism for empty fields. However, I am not sure if that mechanism triggers with Remove Extra Spaces check box. Or, that check box clears out extra spaces in a field.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend creating a separate "Building Departments" table that you would relate to your buildings feature class.  For example, your buildings feature class could use a Building Name field, or an ID field that uses a GUID-like format as your Primary Key.  The Building Departments table would then have two columns, the Foreign Key (which is the Primary Key on the buildings feature class), and the Department Name.

Then, using instructions provided here ([How To: Label a related table](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012230)), you would create a label from the related table on the buildings feature class using Python code.  If you choose to limit how many departments you want labelled for each building (say, maybe no more than 5 departments, even if a building has more), you could alter your code to do so alphabetically or you could even add a field to your table to prioritize or a field to flag whether or not they should be labelled.  That way, you can still track this information and query it, but not necessarily label them all.